# Drop Down In Ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2

Hello guys I'm new to ionic. I'm trying to implement a drop having a list of users in it just like the Facebook one when you share a post on a friends time line. but the thing is I can't understand how can I implement such a drop down. Please help me out. Until now I have done this

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.users = [
       {id:1, name:"John"},
       {id:2, name:"Sue"},
       {id:3, name:"Marc"}
     ]
  });
```

```css
.styled-select {
   background: url(http://i62.tinypic.com/15xvbd5.png) no-repeat 96% 0;
   height: 35px;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 240px;
   color:white;
}
.blue    { background-color: #387EF5; }

.semi-square {
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/css/ionic.css">
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/js/ionic.js">
</script>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
     <div class="row" ng-controller="myCtrl">
       <select  class="styled-select blue semi-square center" ng-model="userAction" ng-change="getUserActionDisabled(userAction)" style="width: 100%!important">
         <option ng-repeat="user in users" value="{{user.id}}" >{{user.name}}</option>
       </select>
     </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this Ionic 1 doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#select) about 'select inputs'. Select inputs are dropdowns. 
For your purpose, you could do something like

```
<div class="list row" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <label class="item item-input item-select">
    <div class="input-label">
    Users
    </div>
    <select class="styled-select blue semi-square center" 
            ng-model="userAction" 
            ng-change="getUserActionDisabled(userAction)" 
            style="width: 100%!important">
      <option ng-repeat="user in users" value="{{user.id}}">{{user.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</div>
```

P.S. I see you're using Angular 1.x, but you have Ionic 2 in the tags. (Ionic 2 is only compatible with Angular 2) :)